# d3.js map lines interrupted

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm developing a d3.js map. I plotted points on a few countries and I connected those points with arcs. The problem is that some arcs are interrupted.

[image: Interrupted arcs on map]

```html
 gArcs.append("path")
   .datum({
     type: "LineString",
     coordinates:[
       [data.dataArray[i].long_from, data.dataArray[i].lat_from], 
       [data.dataArray[i].long_to, data.dataArray[i].lat_to]
     ]
   })
   .attr("class", "arc")
   .attr("d", path)
   .style({
     'stroke': lineColor,
     'stroke-width':lineWidth,
   })
```

Any Ideas on how to draw the arcs without getting interrupted?

Comment: I don't see any interrupted arcs. The one arc depicted is the [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) connecting Kansas City and Alice Springs projected on your map. It just gets clipped at the latitude of your choice. So, what is your question?

Comment: Hi altocumulus, I just would to not use the shortest path and have a continous arc on my map, over the Africa for the one in my example. thx

Comment: Have a look at http://grokbase.com/t/gg/d3-js/138wqyv0ac/straight-lines-on-map-in-d3-js and [*"Straight lines on map in d3.js"*](/q/18493505)

Comment: Thanks, I seen that example before I will try it. but I would to keep arcs and no straight if possible ^^

Comment: Well, then use a path to draw an arc between both points. There are numerous ways to do that. Just avoid the path generator which will project the great circle risking some unwanted clipping.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Sorry i'm a newbie in d3.js and in mapping :). thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: This is not about D3 or mapping anymore but rather about drawing curved paths in SVGs. You should be looking for tutorials like [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html) or [this](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-paths-curve-commands/) dealing with path commands for curves. This allows you to connect any two points on the plane your mapped gets projected on. Again, you don't want them projected, you need a curved path you are going to have to draw on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I chose the solution to draw straight lines with projected points on my maps to avoid interrupted arcs.

```
features.selectAll("path")
  .data(data.dataArray)
  .enter().append("line")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.country_name_from == countryNameFrom
  })
  .attr("x1", function (d) {
    return projection([d.long_from,d.lat_from])[0];
  })
  .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return projection([d.long_from,d.lat_from])[1];
  })
  .attr("x2", function (d) {
    return projection([d.long_to,d.lat_to])[0];
  })
  .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return projection([d.long_to,d.lat_to])[1];
  })
  .attr("d", path)
  .style({
    'stroke': lineColor,
    'stroke-width':lineWidth,
  })
```